# Abrir arquivo GDB

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema no qual preciso utilizar a database vinda de outro sistema, um sistema de vendas.

Esse sistema de vendas é bem antigo e o arquivo onde é mantido o banco de dados tem o formato **.GDB**. Os produtos, transações e tudo mais são armazenados nesse arquivo.

Alguém poderia falar mais sobre esse tipo de extensão de banco de dados assim como possa ser manipulado, como softwares que o abrem?

Comment: Olá João Pedro. Acredito que este seja um arquivo do InterBase antes da versão 7 gerava arquivos .GDB, mas hoje gera arquivos .IB, neste caso acredito que vale a pena tentar abrir com este programa, caso não consiga com uma versão nova tente com uma que foi criada na época que o arquivo foi criado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arquivos coma a extensão GDB são arquivos do Borland/Firebird. Você pode abri-los com o IBExpert: http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/.

É necessário usuário e senha para abrir, o padrão é:

Usuário: SYSDBA

Senha: masterkey

Comment: Ainda não tentei mais foi excelente a resposta. Matou minha dúvida sobre o que é e como abrir. Muito obrigado